# Unable to run SSIS package from Xp_cmdshell called from .nET Aplication

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, jobs

I have a .net application from which I call a job in which I call a stored procedure which has the follwing command-
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /SQL "\DataLoadMasterPackage"' , no_output

On running the application nothing happens. No error as well.

On running package individually from the SSMS it is working fine.

Note : I have configured server to run xp_cmdshell
       I have tried running the execute statement from SSMS and it is executed without giving any error.

What can I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please attach the error.

If the syntax is written is true, then I think your problem is permissions.

Comment: Hi..I was finally able to resolve the issue.Yes the issue was permissions but I wasnt able to figure out which one exactly.I used the following set of queries to see what was running behind and get the error message.

Comment: SET cmdline = 'dtexec /SQL "\DataLoadMasterPackage"'
SET errorMessage = ''
  
--Dump result into temp table
INSERT #tempTable
EXEC ReturnCode = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmdline
 
-- If we have an error populate variable
IF ReturnCode <> 0 BEGIN
  SELECT ErrorMessage = cmdShellOutput FROM #tempTable
  WHERE cmdShellOutput IS NOT NULL
END
--Delete temp table
--DROP TABLE #tempTable
select * from #tempTable

--Display error message and return code
PRINT errorMessage
PRINT returnCode